# With IF and IFERROR im gettnig #DIV/0

Tags: google-sheets

im tryig to setup a formula where for example

B2 will always be -1, cos B1 is empty

and lets say

E2 will aways return #DIV/0, cos from target E1 will be populated with some number and F1 will aways be blanck,

explation is simplified, but its about growth %

```
=if((B1/C1)-1=-1;"-";iferror((B1/C1-1)*SIGN(C1);"-"))
```

with that formula i manage to get b2 to display "-", but E2 draggig formula to it, displays #DIV/0

but if i use only

```
=iferror((B1/C1-1)*SIGN(C1);"-")
```

it manages to get the error and display "-"

what am i missing trying to combine if and iferror in this case? cant spot my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(IF((B1/C1)-1=-1; "-"; (B1/C1-1)*SIGN(C1)); "-")
```